# Java Regex validate username length

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java regex to validate an username. They have to meet the following constraints:

1. Username can contain alphanumeric characters and/or underscore(_).
2. Username can not start with a numeric character.
3. 8 ≤ |Username| ≤ 30

I ended up with the following regex:

```
String regex="^([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*){8,30}$";
```

The problem is that usernames with length > 30 aren't prevented although the one with length < 8 are prevented. What is the wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
String pattern = "^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]{7,29}$";
```

`^[A-Za-z_]` ensures input starts with an alphabet or underscore and then `[A-Za-z0-9_]{7,29}$` makes sure there are 7 to 29 of word characters in the end making total length `8` to `30`.

Or you can shorten it to:

```
String pattern = "^[A-Za-z_]\\w{7,29}$";
```

You regex is trying to match 8 to 30 instances of `([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)` which means start with an alphabet or underscore followed by a word char of any length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"^[A-Za-z][\\w_]{7,29}$"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.